# Understanding URL mapping using DispatcherServlet using alwaysUseFullPath property

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have tried to configure the URLs in my DispatcherServlet to map to URLs without an extension.  I finally figured this out, but I don't understand why the URL is working out the way it is.

Assuming a context of 'foobar'... if the url-pattern for the DispatcherServlet is /rest/* and I have a RequestMapping of /rest/js, then in order to get to the page, I have to go to hostname:port/foobar/rest/rest/js .  Why does the URL have a double /rest/rest on it?

This doesn't make sense, because if I have multiple DispatcherServlets, couldn't the same RequestMapping go to different URLs?  i.e. if the RequestMapping is '/js', and I have a DispatcherServlet set to go to /rest/* and another set to /json/*, then wouldn't hostname:port/foobar/rest/js and hostname:port/foobar/json/js return the same page?

I can't get the URL to come up at all if the @RequestMapping is on the class definition - it only works on the method.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:beans.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="my.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Handlers -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- View Resolvers -->

<bean id="defaultViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
    p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

JServicesController.java:

```
@Controller
public class JServicesController {

    @Autowired
    private TheService theService;


    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/rest/js")
    public TheContent getTheContent() {
        return theService.getTheContent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Assuming a context of 'foobar'... if the url-pattern for the DispatcherServlet is /rest/* and I have a RequestMapping of /rest/js, then in order to get to the page, I have to go to hostname:port/foobar/rest/rest/js . Why does the URL have a double /rest/rest on it?

The idea is that you can have multiple `DispatcherServlets` and you have to differentiate between one and another.

You can, for example have one dispatcher serving documents @ `/documents/` and another serving images @ `/images` and then have a `@RequestMapping("/whatever")` for both of them serving different things.

If double `rest/rest` irritates you, then you can map your dispatcher to serve `/`·

> ...  then wouldn't hostname:port/foobar/rest/js and hostname:port/foobar/json/js return the same page?

Only if you configure them to do so. Each dispatcher can `component-scan` different packages and have different request mappings for the same path.

Comment: Any idea why I can't get this to work at all when I put the @RequestMapping on the type definition?  It only works on the method, unlike the multitude of examples that I've seen.

Comment: It's the same code I already have posted, except you'd move the @RequestMapping("/rest/js") to the class level.

Comment: i think you need to annotate both class and methods for that to work, otherwise spring treats the methods as normal public methods, not RequestMappings.

Comment: @acvcu or, quoting the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#value()) `In case of Servlet-based handler methods, the method names are taken into account for narrowing if no path was specified explicitly, according to the specified MethodNameResolver (by default an InternalPathMethodNameResolver). Note that this only applies in case of ambiguous annotation mappings that do not specify a path mapping explicitly.`

Comment: @acvcu so method names are also taken into consideration, but only if the mapping is ambigous. You have to annotate methods anyway, even if you annotate the class.

Comment: Hmm... it seems like the `rest/rest` behaviour you had is what setting `alwaysUseFullPath` normally prevents. Did you ever figure out why that didn't work?

Comment: Why am I losing a servlet after putting / in the end of the key. Example in my dispatcher i have <prop key="books.htm">bookServlet</prop> and in the servlet itself I use RequestMapping for detailed method handling. But if I now change the url to .../book.htm/doSomething I lose the servlet. How do i handle such a case.