# Why dispatch from one servlet to another double the pathInfo?

Tags: java, servlets

Hi and please excuse my english,

I have one main servlet which dispatch all user action and one to manage request to DAO Java class. First action (click on menu) works and give me the right URL: projet/admin/groupes/gerer (project/admin/bands/manage). Second action (click on button) double the pathInfo: projet/admin/groupes/admin/groupes/creer (create).

If I take the double path into account, it works but it's not a good solution (and if I try to click on the menu again, it triple!)

Calls to servlet come from a JavaScript :

```
switch (name) {
    case 'Groupe':                          // Click on band menu from administration side
        console.log('JS: Click on admin menu Groupe');
        var url = "admin/groupes/gerer";
        location.href = url;
        break;

    case 'Creer':                           // Click on 'Creer' button from liste-groupe page
        console.log('JS : click on Creer');
        var url = "admin/groupes/creer";
        location.href = url;
        break;

    default:
        console.log('JS: no click source');
}
```

Main servlet with urlPattern: "/admin/groupes/*", I should write "/creer" on the second case.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
    servletPath = request.getServletPath();
    System.out.println("BandController, pathInfo: " + pathInfo); // TEST CODE
    System.out.println("BandController, servletPath: " + servletPath); // TEST CODE

    switch (pathInfo) {

        // Dispatch to the management servlet
        case "/gerer":
            System.out.println("BandController : groupes (menu) > BandManagement"); // TEST CODE
            dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("/action/gerer/listergrp");
            dispatch.forward(request, response);
            break;

        // FIXME fix double URL call!
        case "/admin/groupes/creer" :
            System.out.println("BandController : liste-groupes.jsp > nouvellefiche.jsp"); // TEST CODE
            dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/nouvellefiche.jsp");
            dispatch.forward(request, response);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("BandController : page 404."); // TEST CODE
            break;

}
```

I hope that's enough information, I tried several different kind of path in the RequestDispatcher without success. And I just find this topic [Understanding URL mapping using DispatcherServlet using alwaysUseFullPath property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131946/understanding-url-mapping-using-dispatcherservlet-using-alwaysusefullpath-proper)  which talk about double path but didn't understand the answer.

Thanks for any help (by the way I'm a Java beginner!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you're not referencing the context path at the JavaScript calls. Change your JS code to:

```
switch (name) {
    case 'Groupe': // Click on band menu from administration side
        console.log('JS: Click on admin menu Groupe');
        var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/groupes/gerer";
        location.href = url;
        break;

    case 'Creer': // Click on 'Creer' button from liste-groupe page
        console.log('JS : click on Creer');
        var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/groupes/creer";
        location.href = url;
        break;

    default:
        console.log('JS: no click source');
}
```

This way, you'll always guarantee that the request URL will be formed from the project context path.

---

**EDIT:**

In case you're making the call from a JS file, the EL won't work once it is not inside a JSP page, directly. For this, you can store the context path in a hidden input field ang get its value at your JavaScript code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
```

**JS:**

```
var contextPath = document.getElementById('contextPath').value;
switch (name) {
    case 'Groupe': 
        var url = contextPath;
        location.href = url;
        break;

// ...
```

Comment: Hi there and thanks for your answer.

I just thought this morning that I probably needed to add the path context! Because when I send a form directly to my main servlet with <%=request.getContextPath()%> it works (I still need to learn about the EL!)

So it looks like you're using EL in a JavaScript file? It doesn't work for me but maybe I'm missing one step here?

Comment: (Sorry first use of StackOverFlow... I can't edit anymore.)
The browser try to reach this URL: **/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/admin/groupes/gerer**

Comment: This happens because JS file doesn't have access to request scope obj. Take a look at my edit. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!

It works, I just need to put the input on every JSP page that needed it but that's OK, it can go in the footer which is include everywhere for example.

Just to say, I was trying this way (given by my trainer) which works too ;)
`function getContext() {
    var currentLocation = document.location.href;
    var contextPath = currentLocation.split("/");
    var url = "/" + contextPath + "/admin/groupes/gerer";
}`

Comment: Yeah, it suits too. :)

Comment: Yes I did, click on the tick and on the up arrow. :)